# Modelagem - Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, modelagem

Estou com dificuldades em criar minhas models.

Vamos imaginar que tenho 4 tipos diferentes de produtos (Aqui como A,B,C e D)

```
public class Produto
{
    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
    public TipoProduto TipoProduto { get; set; } //enum tipo
}
```

Porém os produtos do Tipo A (`TipoProduto==A`) ele pode ser desmontado e com isso cria-se 4 novos pedaços, nos quais também quero cadastrar. (até ai vou cadastrar uma model chamado ProdutosTipoAPartes)
Pensei em criar uma outra Model onde eu poderia armazenar o Id do produto base

```
public class ProdutoTipoA
{
    public int ProdutoTipoAId { get; set; }
    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
//caracteristicas específicas do tipo A
    public virtual Produto Produto { get; set; }
}
```

os produtos do tipoB

```
public class ProdutoTipoB
{
    public int ProdutoTipoBId { get; set; }
    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
//caracteristicas específicas do tipo B
    public virtual Produto Produto { get; set; }
}
```

Essa abordagem é correta? na model Produtos eu teria algum tipo de relacionamento virtual com os outros tipos `A`,`B`,`C` ou `D` ?

Ou é melhor eu criar:

```
public class ProdutoBase
{
    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
    public TipoProduto TipoProduto { get; set; } //enum tipo
    public string Serial { get; set; }
}
```

e os ProdutosA, ProdutosB herdar o base?

```
public class ProdutoTipoA : ProdutoBase
    {
    //caracteristicas específicas do tipo A
    }
```

E para completar, terei os pedidos, que serão vinculados aos Produtos, por isso que ficaria complexo se eu tivesse vários tipos de Model Produtos.
Não sei por qual caminho ir.

---

Update:
As opções que vejo são:

- Criar a Classe base e os produtos A,B,C e D herdar
- Criar um Produto e outros produtos que são hierarquicamente inferiores, como se fosse produtos filhos.

  - Criar 4 produtos separados e transformar minha vida em uma loucura..

Comment: por que não criar uma class produto com uma propriedade tipo e atribuída a um enum?

Comment: Corrigi uma linha no código, você tinha herdado `ProdutoTipoB` na classe `ProdutoTipoA` , troquei para `ProdutoBase`, não sei se está correto, caso não esteja cancelo a edição.

Comment: não ela herdaria do produtoBase

Comment: @DamonDudek já tem o enum para o tipo de produto..veja TipoProduto , o problema é que produtos A,B,C,D tem uns 6 campos cada um diferente, então por isso como separar as models mas manter um vinculo..e ainda o Produto B terá sub-produtos...pra complicar

Comment: O seu caso seria Produto que pode ser desmontado e vendido em partes? E essas partes você queria que fossem cada uma delas um novo Produto e assim sucessivamente?

Comment: @LeandroSimões exato, para o ProdutoA eu posso dividir ele em várias partes, mas os produtos B,C não.. então não sei se crio 4 models independentes? se herdo elas? se faço uma relacionar com outra?. até pq no pedido eu irei armazenar qual id?,,rs

Comment: Olá, Se tu precisa somente identificar o tipo do produto para uma lógica simples e pequena, sugiro criar um atributo na classe com o Enum do produto. Do contrário, em necessidade de uma lógica mais robusta, acredito que seria melhor ter uma classe pai com os atributos e métodos em comum e as outras herdando desta classe.

Comment: veja que já criei esse enum public TipoProduto TipoProduto { get; set; } //enum tipo o que quero é produtos diferentes que tem uma certa base em comum faço por herança ou hierarquia das models?

Comment: Depende, você tem que avaliar se os produtos podem ter dependências entre si. Se não, utilize a boa e velha herança.

Dá uma olhada neste artigo: http://www.guj.com.br/t/entendendo-a-hierarquia-de-classes-extends-implements/103546

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se tivesse dado um exemplo mais concreto, daria para ajudar melhor. Me parece que vc está trabalhando com **estruturas**.

Vou fazer um exemplo bem superficial. Usando o model abaixo, vamos montar uma estrutura e montar uma caneta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public class Parte
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public string Nome {get;set;}
    public string Propriedades {get;set;}
    public List<Parte> Partes {get;set;}
    public Parte MontaEm {get;set;}

    public Parte()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        Partes = new List<Parte>();
    }

    public Parte MontarEm(Parte parte, string nome)
    {
        MontaEm = parte;
        parte.Partes.Add(this);

        var novaParte = new Parte
        {
            Nome = nome             
        };
        novaParte.Partes.AddRange(new []  { this, parte});

        return novaParte;
    }
}
```

Sempre que vc monta uma parte em outra, uma nova parte é criada. Isso não é simples de controlar, e pode-se adicionar muitos outros recursos, como qual parte pode conectar com qual parte, se pode ser removivel, se pode ser intercambiavel, etc.

```
    var esfera = new Parte
    {
        Nome = "Esfera",
        Propriedades = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( new { Tamanho = 0.1m, Material = "Aluminio" } )         
    };

    var pontaMetalica = new Parte
    {
        Nome = "Ponta Metalica",
        Propriedades = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( new { Material = "Latão", Peso = 0.02m } )
    };

    var pontaClassica = new Parte
    {
        Nome = "Ponta Classica",
        Propriedades = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( new { Material = "Plastico", Comprimento = 0.3m } )
    };

    var cartucho = new Parte
    {
        Nome = "Cartucho",
        Propriedades = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( new { Comprimento = 0.5m, Cor = "Amarela" } )
    };

    var tinta = new Parte
    {
        Nome = "Tinta",
        Propriedades = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( new { Cor = "Azul", Volume = 2m } )
    };

    var pontaEsferografica = esfera.MontarEm(pontaMetalica, "Ponta Esferografica");

    var pontaCompleta = pontaEsferografica.MontarEm(pontaClassica, "Ponta Completa");

    var carga = tinta.MontarEm(pontaCompleta, "Carga de Tinta");

    var cilindro = new Parte
    {
        Nome = "Cilindro",
        Propriedades = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( new { Cor = "Transparente" } )
    };

    var tampa = new Parte
    {
        Nome = "Tampa",
        Propriedades = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( new { Cor = "Azul", PodeRemover = true } )
    };

    var corpo = carga.MontarEm(cilindro, "Corpo Completo");

    var caneta = tampa.MontarEm(corpo, "Caneta Completa");
```

A no final, terá uma estrutura assim:

> - Caneta Completa:
>
>   - Tampa: {"Cor":"Azul","PodeRemover":true}
>   - Corpo Completo:
>   - Carga de Tinta:
>   - Tinta: {"Cor":"Azul","Volume":2.0}
>   - Ponta Completa:
>
>     - Ponta Esferografica:
>     - Esfera: {"Tamanho":0.1,"Material":"Aluminio"}
>     - Ponta Metalica: {"Material":"Latão","Peso":0.02}
>     - Esfera: {"Tamanho":0.1,"Material":"Aluminio"}
>     - Ponta Classica: {"Material":"Plastico","Comprimento":0.3}
>     - Ponta Esferografica:
>     - Esfera: {"Tamanho":0.1,"Material":"Aluminio"}
>     - Ponta Metalica: {"Material":"Latão","Peso":0.02}
>     - Esfera: {"Tamanho":0.1,"Material":"Aluminio"}
>     - Tinta: {"Cor":"Azul","Volume":2.0}
>   - Cilindro: {"Cor":"Transparente"}
>   - Carga de Tinta:
>
>     - Tinta: {"Cor":"Azul","Volume":2.0}
>     - Ponta Completa:
>     - Ponta Esferografica:
>     - Esfera: {"Tamanho":0.1,"Material":"Aluminio"}
>     - Ponta Metalica: {"Material":"Latão","Peso":0.02}
>     - Esfera: {"Tamanho":0.1,"Material":"Aluminio"}
>     - Ponta Classica: {"Material":"Plastico","Comprimento":0.3}
>     - Ponta Esferografica:
>     - Esfera: {"Tamanho":0.1,"Material":"Aluminio"}
>     - Ponta Metalica: {"Material":"Latão","Peso":0.02}
>
>       - Esfera: {"Tamanho":0.1,"Material":"Aluminio"}
>     - Tinta: {"Cor":"Azul","Volume":2.0}
>   - Tampa: {"Cor":"Azul","PodeRemover":true}

[Veja funcionando no Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cPyDjd)